# css alignment for masonry layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

I have tried [masonry.js](http://masonry.desandro.com/) in order to create a masonry grid, but the problem im having is that the longer unit gets overlapped with other units, and the masonry.js for some reason, doesn't fill the area in relation to the content's height at all.

so I figured that I could do it manually by using `:nth-child` selectors.

I want to make it look more like this:

[image]

Here is what I got so far,
http://lifeto.cafe24.com/xe/request

and I want to make the layers not overlap with each other and fill the gap automatically.

Here is the code I'm using:

**css:**

```
*, *:before, *:after {
   box-sizing: border-box !important;
}

 article {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap; 
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.board_list {
   display: block;
}

.list_container {
   height: auto;
   margin: 0 20px 100px;
   padding: 0;
   width: 200px;
   display: inline-block;
}

.list_profile_img_container {
   /* border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; */
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

.list_profile_image {
   border-radius: 100px;
   width: 30px;
   height: 30px;
}

.list_image_thumbnail {
   width: 100%;
   height:100%;
   border-top-left-radius: 5px;
   border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.list_one {
   opacity: 0;
   background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
   box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.176);
   border-radius: 3px;
}
```

**html:**

```
<article>
   <!-- LIST -->
   <div class="list_container">
      <div class="list_one">
      </div>
   </div>
</article>
```

can anyone help me out?

P.S. here is the js script i use for the functionality.

and notice that im using jscroll.js in order to create the infinite scrolling effet and im loading masonry.js within the call back function of the plugin.

```
/* infinite scroll */
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.board_content').jscroll({
    loadingHtml: '<div class="loading_div"><center><img     src="layouts/wb10/ajax-loader4.gif" alt="Loading" /></center></div>',
   padding: 0,
    contentSelector: '.board_list',
    autoTriggerUntil: 30,
    nextSelector:'.next_button',
    callback: function() {

        jQuery('.list_container').masonry({
  // options
  itemSelector: '.list_container',
  columnWidth: 50
});

       jQuery('.list_one').waypoint(function() {
        jQuery('.list_one').addClass('animated fadeIn');
        }, {
         offset: '75%'
   });
 }
}); });
```

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle? it will be much easier to detect the error

Comment: @KhaledAl-Ansari thanks for the help. im afraid it won't exactly generate the same kind of error, as all the contents and pictures are coming from the CMS that im using. can't you spot the error just by looking at the site i cited?

Comment: Somehow the items `.list_container` getting `height:0px`. You need to check who do this and why the height is 0. I think that it's because the item is not `:visible` when the script running so the script find that his height is `0`.  (http://i.stack.imgur.com/AO3Wx.png) Try to run the script only after the all items are shown and let me know the result.

Comment: @ the height:0 on every .list_container is coming from the masonry.js i think. but even when it doesn't do that, the masonry.js is not doing anything that helps the layout becoming masonry layout. At least, if i have height:0 the contents fit into the empty space.

Comment: why u using masonry ? you can use css new features like col (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the elements and I found that every element got `height: 0px;` and that's the problem, what you need to do is to delay the masonry library call until every element in shown on the screen then run the masonry to get the right effect

Comment: can you checked the original post? i just added js script. and can you access the site again? i just erased the masonry.js and that's how it looks like without masonry.js http://lifeto.cafe24.com/xe/request can you give me a hint how to go about this?

Comment: what is the use of jscroll? @MarkKang

Comment: i just got rid of the infinite scrolling just to see how it looks like without it.

Comment: try add the masonry code after loading the window `$(window).load(function(){ /* your code goes here */}` use a library if you want if you want a better load

Comment: i've tried wrapping the script with the code you gave, but nothing happens. i've tried using the http://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html#imagesloaded  but throws 'imagesLoaded is not a function' error.

Comment: nvm, i fixed the error,though im stuck with the alignment problem. but i appreciate your help.

Comment: quick fix make the height auto important like this `.list_container{ height:auto!important; }` this will help you void the height 0 for now